# Find who is selecting from table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, audit

We have a table that has a very long update process that I think was from a no longer used program. No one can seem to tell me if anyone still uses it or not.

What is the best way to log which users read from the table? Build an audit or can I dig through a system log somewhere to find any user that might have read from it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server has a built in [Audit feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) that can be used to track this for you. Here is an article called [**Auditing SELECT statements in SQL Server 2008**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1649/auditing-select-statements-in-sql-server-2008/) that walks through how you can accomplish it. (It's helpful despite being a little dated.)

Aside from that, there's always the scream test.  Just rename the table and see what breaks and who complains.

Additionally, you might be interested in knowing what else may be consuming that Table which you can easily do via SSMS by right clicking it and clicking on *View Dependencies*. Here's [some Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) about that as well. Also, RedGate has a free and helpful tool called [SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) that can help you find the references as well.

Comment: Thanks. I was a fan of the rename it and see who screams, but apparently the powers that be think "it might cause problems". Ruined a lot of fun I think.

Comment: @Toolman21 lol I get it, we can't always have all the fun I guess. Best of luck!